# How do I set an _id value in FactoryBot that isn't a foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, factory

I'm using FactoryBot (formerly FactoryGirl) to create some factory data for my tests. I have a model that looks like this via the schema (stripped down to just the relevant stuff):

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "team"
    t.text "feature_id"
    t.text "feature"
    t.timestamps
end
```

However, `feature_id` and `feature` are NOT references to a feature object... they are just strings.

I've defined my factory like this:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :item do
    team "TheTeam"
    sequence(:feature_id) {|n| "Feature#{n}" }
    feature { Faker::Lorem.sentence }
  end
end
```

And the simple case works:

```
> FactoryBot.create(:item)
=> #<Item:0x007fad8cbfc048
 id: 1,
 team: "TheTeam",
 feature_id: "Feature1",
 feature: "Qui voluptatem animi et rerum et.",
 created_at: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 02:40:01 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 02:40:01 UTC +00:00>
```

But when I want to specify my own `feature_id` this is what happens:

```
> FactoryBot.create(:item, feature_id: "123")
=> #<Item:0x007fad8d30a880
 id: 2,
 team: "TheTeam",
 feature_id: "123",
 feature: nil,
 created_at: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 02:40:59 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 02:40:59 UTC +00:00>
```

You can see that `feature` is now `nil`. I'm assuming this is because it's trying to infer that `feature_id` and `feature` are somehow related. But in this case, I don't want them to be.

**Is there a better way to define the factory so that it just treats them as unrelated fields?**

BTW, if I try to set both the `feature_id` and `feature` it looks like this:

```
> FactoryBot.create(:item, feature_id: "123", feature: "hi")
=> #<Item:0x007fad8d262810
 id: 3,
 team: "TheTeam",
 feature_id: nil,
 feature: nil,
 created_at: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 02:45:01 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Wed, 10 Jan 2018 02:45:01 UTC +00:00>
```

So it just sets both fields to `nil`. I suspect FactoryBot is trying to be "smart" about these fields based on their names. I'd change them but they are already set that way in the Db.

Comment: Does this model work as expected if you create a record outside of FactoryBot? For example, if you do `Item.create(team: 'TheTeam', feature_id: '123', feature: 'Description of feature')`, do you get a record with all attributes saved?

Comment: Great question, @moveson. Yes, it works via console to just do what you had there. I don't have any validations on fields and don't have any relationships (at this time). The Item class doesn't reference anything else. So Rails itself is fine with it. It just seems to be something within FactoryBot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does appear that FactoryBot is making assumptions, and I haven't found a way to change those assumptions. It might be worth opening an issue to see what the maintainers have to offer.

In the mean time, here's a workaround:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  FEATURE_IDS ||= (1..1000).cycle

  factory :item do
    team "TheTeam"

    transient { without_feature_id false }
    transient { without_feature false }

    after(:build, :stub) do |item, evaluator|
      item.feature_id = "Feature#{FEATURE_IDS.next}" unless evaluator.without_feature_id
      item.feature = Faker::Lorem.sentence unless evaluator.without_feature
    end
  end
end
```

This will function properly in the cases you described above.

The incrementing is tricky. I was not able to find a way to use FactoryBot sequences outside of the resource-construction context, so I use an Enumerator and call `#next` to create the sequence. This works similar to a FactoryBot sequence, except that there is no way to reset to 1 in the middle of a test run.

RSpec tests prove it works as expected, whether we are creating items in the database or building them in memory:

```
context 'when more than one item is created' do
  let(:item_1) { create(:item) }
  let(:item_2) { create(:item) }

  it 'increments feature_id by 1' do
    expect(item_1.feature_id).to be_present
    expect(item_2.feature_id).to eq(item_1.feature_id.next)
  end
end

context 'when using build instead of create' do
  let(:item_1) { build(:item) }
  let(:item_2) { build(:item) }

  it 'increments feature_id by 1' do
    expect(item_1.feature_id).to be_present
    expect(item_2.feature_id).to eq(item_1.feature_id.next)
  end
end
```

Note that you cannot create an item without a feature_id or a feature using the typical construct; for example:

```
>> item = create(:item, feature_id: nil)
```

Will result in

```
>> item.feature_id
#> "Feature1"
```

If you wish to create an object without the feature and feature_id fields, you can do:

```
create(:item, without_feature_id: true, without_feature: true)
```

Comment: This looks good, although is there a way to still get the `sequence` part for `feature_id` in the `after()` block? It's a quibble, but it would be nice to have the `feature_id` be a sequentially incrementing `Feature1`, `Feature2`, etc like `sequence` provides

Comment: I like this a lot! I think instead of providing a constant, though, it could be this: `item.feature_id = "Feature#{item.class.count + 1}" unless evaluator.without_feature_id
` which then just adds 1 to the number of items. So it won't reset, but otherwise should work. It does add an extra DB call for each creation, but at least for now that's not a problem.

Comment: Keep in mind that you may not want to create items in the database every time. Often (hopefully very often) you will instead want to just build items in memory using `build` or `build_stubbed`. For that reason, I would avoid an incremental value that relies on the database. That said, I misstated the way this incremental variable works. In fact, it will reset at the beginning of a test run, not at the start of each unit test, which is probably what you want in any case.

Comment: Ahhh... good call. Yes, having it rely on the DB count would be problematic in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: One interesting thing to note: if I change the attributes to be `feature_id` and `feature_title`, everything works in the original setup. So it definitely is because of the `X_id` and `X` naming pattern somehow.

Comment: Yes, I'm not surprised at all by this, as it follows [ActiveRecord naming convention](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#naming-conventions).